# run .exe file from web application

Tags: php, web-services, exe

I have application called [unistat](http://www.unistat.com/) installed on my pc. I want to pass an argument from a web page and retrieve output from that program.

Is this possible? 
How i can connect the website based on PHP to a remote desktop? ask to run .exe file by passing data and send output to specific location?

Comment: It's not really possible through programmatic means, but can be done... This question may be better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access your local machine from the remote server, you're going to have to open up your router configuration settings and port forward all incoming port 80 traffic to your local web server's IP.

On your local machine, install PHP and set up an endpoint that runs the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command, calling the .exe you wish to run.

You'd be wise to put this behind an authentication system, as it will be exposed to the www.

On the remote site, just fire a request off to the local machine's endpoint and the exec command will be run. Of course, if you have a dynamic IP, it's going to require constant maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jordan, If i install PHP on local machine, output will gonna stay on local machine isn't it? My web app is on linux server. and i have local machine at my office.

Comment: What kind of output is it exactly? When you run the .exe in the console does it return text, write to a file, or launch a GUI application...?

Comment: its an adding to excel. it can generate txt,img,and word type of output. you can run in stand alone mode as well as background process.

Comment: Alright, so it is writing to a file. PHP's exec() will wait until the command is finished executing. Depending on the format (txt is probably best), read it back into PHP and echo it out. It will shown in the browser. Try that first, then if you wish ...on your remote server, perform an AJAX request instead of direct GET request, and it can be captured by JavaScript and displayed on the remote site. Does this help?

Comment: Hi Jordan, as far as i know exec function will run commands on same server only. I want to run command on windows server. application is installed on windows machine and my web app is on linux os. i want to run windows command from linux server.

Comment: @HeenaAgheda: You're correct. `exec()` command will run on the same server only. That means you need PHP + Apache on the Windows server. This Apache server listens for requests to http://your.windows.ip.address/yourscript.php and when it receives one, fires the `exec()` command, which runs the .exe, grabs the output, and echoes it to the browser that called it. This will of course change the URL, so, if you need to obtain the results and embed them in the webapp, you'll need to perform an AJAX request instead. This also assumes your ISP plan will allow incoming web traffic.

Comment: I don't know first of all how i can reach to windows machine and put some file in that dir.

Comment: ssh2 may make my life easier i think

Comment: It very well could. [See SSH2 PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php)

Answer (score 0):

See the following link about setting up custom protocols on Windows:

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/86754-launching-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http

The idea would be that your web site could direct the browser to a special URL, i.e. `unistat://my-data-goes-here` and the application would be triggered with this data.

edit: better, MSDN link on the subject.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

edit2: Just realized you want to pipe the output from the EXE back to the webserver.... You may be better off building a browser extension.  That, or writing a wrapper around unistat which can trap the output and submit it to a web service.

Comment: Thanks Fosco, as long as i can connect and read directory from local machine from PHP. It will do i guess. Because once i get access to local machine and how to run .exe file, PHP can read output file from local machine.